# How does gradle solve conflicts when two dependencies have an internal dependency on the same library but with different versions in Android?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My app has dependencies on two libraries. Both of them use the same library '**org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core**' but different versions internally.

```
androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' //(Depends on version 1.3)
androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19' //(Depends on version 1.1)
```

Since both the dependencies are related to `Android instrumentation tests`, the app builds successfully and includes the higher version in the build - in this case version 1.3.

But if I use one library for the main app and other library for Android Instrumentation tests as follows:

```
compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
```

I get the following error.

```
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
Conflict with dependency 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core'. Resolved versions for app (1.3) and test app (1.1) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies'.
> Dependency Error. See console for details.
```

So I went to the link given in the exception. The reason for this behavior is given as follows

> When instrumentation tests are run, both the main APK and test APK share the same classpath. Gradle build will fail if the main APK and the test APK use the same library (e.g. Guava) but in different versions. If gradle didn't catch that, your app could behave differently during tests and during normal run (including crashing in one of the cases).

Upto this point I don't have any problem, but I have a problem in the following cases:

1) In the below declaration, only one main apk is created because local unit tests run on the JVM, then why does this fail with the same exception of conflict

```
compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
```

2) And if the above is failing, so this should also fail. But surprisingly, this works fine and builds fine.

```
 androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
```

I am not able to understand this ambiguous nature with which `gradle` solves dependencies in `Android`.